# java recursion in Depth first algorithm order. Deeper and Deeper getAccumulated value

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

This problem may not be clear to everyone. I will try my best go describe the problem here. 
This is Problem has recursion, which follows DFS Algorithm.

I have an Object `ABC` like this

```
public class ABC
{
    private List<ABC> children;
    private int x;

    public ABC(int x)
    {
        children= new ArrayList<ABC>();
        this.x=x;
    }

    public void addChildren(ABC ob)
    {
        children.add(ob);
    }
    public List<ABC> getChidlren()
    {
        return children;    
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

This is the data this object going to hold..

```
ABC a1= new ABC(1);
ABC a2= new ABC(2);
ABC a3= new ABC(2);
ABC a4= new ABC(2);
ABC a5= new ABC(2);
ABC a6= new ABC(2);
ABC a7= new ABC(4);
ABC a8= new ABC(4);

a6.addChildren(a7);
a6.addChildren(a8);

a5.addChildren(a6);
a4.addChildren(a5);
a3.addChildren(a4);
a2.addChildren(a3);
a1.addChildren(a2);
```

Simply, `a1` has `a2` as child, `a2` has `a3` as child and so on. There is no rule to have only one child. Any object can have any number of children.

```
                ABC {x=1}
                 ____|___________________ _ _ _ 
                |         |
             ABC{x=2}   ABC{x=2} .........
         _____|______
         |
       ABC {x=30}
        ____|___________________ _ _ _ 
       |         |
      ABC{x=5}   ABC{x=12} .........
```

**My problem is**

I have to create a utility class with a method which takes an `ABC` object as argument. This method has the responsibility to create an Object "XYZ" with the total value "ABC" and its children.

Example 1, I have an ABC object "myObject" with value x=56; 
so my utility method will take "myObject" and returns a "XYZ" object with it's value "56".

Example 2, I have ABC Object "myObject2" with value is x="46". It has one child "myObject 3" with value "54". Now my utility method should return me a "XYZ" with it's value "100". "XYZ will have a child whose value is "46"".
(Actually I am asking for accumulated values of ABC and its children in an Object format in every level)

My XYZ.java is:

```
public class XYZ
{
   private List<XYZ> children;
   private int value;


   XYZ(int value)
   {
      children= new ArrayList<XYZ>();
      this.value=value;
   }

   public void addChildren(XYZ xyz)
   {
      value=value+xyz.getValue();
      children.add(xyz);
   }

   public List<XYZ> getChildren()
   {
      return children;
   }    

   public int getValue()
   {
      return value; 
   }
}
```

My utility method in Utility.java looks is:

I know this is not right. I need your help to implement this method.

```
public XYZ getFinalValue(ABC obj)
{
   int finalValue;
   XYZ h = null;

   //go inside, look for it's value.
   //return that values if obj has no children.
   //If Obj has a child, accumulate Its value with it's children value

   if(obj.getChidlren().size()==0)
   {
      h = new XYZ(obj.getValue());
      finalValue= obj.getValue();            
   }
   else
   {
      for(ABC ob:obj.getChidlren())
      {
         XYZ hu=getFinalValue(ob);
         h.addChildren(hu);
      }
   }         
   return h;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make the variable `finalValue` accumulate the values without creating the `XYZ` object. You don't need the `h` value.

```
public XYZ getFinalValue(ABC obj)
{
   int finalValue = 0;

   //go inside, look for it's value.
   //return that values if obj has no children.
   //If Obj has a child, accumulate Its value with it's children value

   finalValue = obj.getValue();             
   if(obj.getChidlren().size() > 0)
   {
      for(ABC ob:obj.getChidlren())
      {
         finalValue += getFinalValue(ob);
      }
   }
   return new XYZ(finalValue);
}
```

Why is the depth of the recursion important? It says so in your title, but I don't see how it will matter?

Comment: There's a problem with your code. You're returning the variable `h` and it has no value. Maybe you're trying to do `public int getFinalValue(ABC obj)` and `return finalValue;`

Comment: You still returning an XYZ object -_-' :-)